# How to display loading graphics in Firefox in Microsoft Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, reporting

I am using MS reporting services and some of the reports are taking longer than it should. By default the report viewer displays a loading graphics in IE. However, this graphics is not visible in Firefox. It works fine in IE. How can I display the loading graphics in Firefox?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Niraj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My SSRS 2005 server displays the loading icon just fine in Firefox, IE and Chrome.